# chrome not breaking the page while printing stickers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, page-break

I am trying to print multiple stickers on A4 size paper via chrome browser (Version 55.0.2883.87) but unfortunately stickers get cut off from the bottom if they do not fit on the page. There are large number of stickers and I'm printing 2 in a row.

```
<script language="javascript">
      function printPage(){

          window.print();   
      }
      </script>
      <style type="text/css">
      @media print {
      .donotprint {
          display:none;
      }
      }
      @media screen {
      .donotprint {
          display:block;
      }
      }
      </style>
```

on this page there are few sections which I don't want to print so I have given them class 'donotprint' and discarded. These stickers are working fine in other browsers and automatically breaks the page when stickers are not fitting on the page but in chrome they printing refer to the image shown below.
[image]
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried properties like `page-break-inside` etc?